# Is it possible to "render" a template in code (without triggering parent change detection)

Tags: angular

I have the folling template code:

```html
<app-filterable-select
  formControlName="customer"
  [options]="customers"
  [filterFn]="filterCustomer"
>
  <ng-template let-customer>{{ customer.name }}, {{ customer.location }}</ng-template>
</app-filterable-select>
```

Now, in the filterable select, I have a method that is supposed to return the currently selected value as text (if it exists). Of course, I would like to use the existing template for that, so this is the code I'm currently using:

```js
protected get triggerValue() {
  if (this.selected) {
    const e = this.contentRef.createEmbeddedView({ $implicit: this.selected });
    e.detectChanges();

    return e.rootNodes[0].textContent;
  }

  return "";
}
```

(This is how I obtain the reference to the template: `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) protected contentRef!: TemplateRef<unknown>;`).

Sadly this causes:

> ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'Customer...'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?

I suppose `get triggerValue()` is called after change detection happened, but in this scenario, I don't really care about it. I only want to use the user defined template "in an encapsulated / detached way", get the display value, and dispose of the view immediately after.

I also tried calling `e.detatch()`, which did not change the outcome. I suppose it was never really connected to any change trees in the first place, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Essentally: **I don't need change detection trees (that bubble) etc., just the display value of that template**.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping away from the problem made me suddenly realize, that my mind was stuck in the [existing implementation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/select/select.ts), and I could *obviously* just use:

```html
<span class="mat-select-min-line">
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="contentRef"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: value }"
  ></ng-container>
</span>
```

instead of:

```html
<span class="mat-select-min-line">{{ triggerValue }}</span>
```

in the template.

While this is not a direct answer to the question, maybe it helps someone in the future.